# NestJS GRPC call.sendMetadata - how to get metadata on the client?

Tags: nestjs

I'm trying to send a metadata from the server side gprc using NestJS framework. On the official NestJS guide [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/grpc#grpc-metadata): it shows a example of doing the server side grpc metadata:

```
@Controller()
export class HeroesService {
    @GrpcMethod()
    findOne(data: HeroById, metadata: Metadata, call: ServerUnaryCall<any>): Hero {
        const serverMetadata = new Metadata();
        const items = [
          { id: 1, name: 'John' },
          { id: 2, name: 'Doe' },
        ];
    
        serverMetadata.add('Set-Cookie', 'yummy_cookie=choco');
        call.sendMetadata(serverMetadata);
    
        return items.find(({ id }) => id === data.id);
    }
}
```

and how to get metadata on the client?

client side code:

```
getHero(): Observable<string> {
    return this.heroesService.findOne({ id: 1 });
  }
```